# Is there any natural construction for the irreducible representations of $G\wr S_n$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

For $S_n,$ one can construct all the irreducible representations through the young diagrams. Is there any natural construction for the irreducible representation of $G\wr S_n$ (G is a finite group)?

Comment: It depends what you mean by natural. In Theorem 4.3.34 of James and Kerber's book "The Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group" a complete list of irreducible representations is obtained via Clifford theory. However this is probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Munees: Besides the older symmetric group literature, the more recent work on rational Cherednik algebras might be suggestive.  But as Jay points out, it depends on what is meant by "natural".

Comment: @munees: you might also see this previous post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25625/reference-request-representation-theory-of-the-hyperoctahedral-group